# How to detect/redirect URL with language prefix

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I currently have a single website running in 2 languages, on 2 domains, but using a language prefix in the URLs to define German content. Both languages can be accessed on both domains as follows:

> **English content** 
>   mysite.com/content/wonderful  
>   mysite.de/content/wonderful
>
> **German content**  
> mysite.com/de/content/wunderbar  
> mysite.de/de/content/wunderbar

I will change to domain language selection, so that one language is accessible on one domain:

> **English** 
>  mysite.com/content/wonderful
>   **German** 
>  mysite.de/content/wunderbar

**The problem:** We have a lot of content that has been bookmarked and URLs which have been published in print. 75% of our content's links will be changed, meaning many a 404.

Is there a wildcard 301 for sending all `.com/de/content` and `.de/de/content` to `.de/content`?

Comment: So all `.com/de/content` and `.com/de/content` is to go to `.de/content` and all `.de/content` is to go to `.com/content`? If so,  it cause both german and english content to be redirect to the `.com/content`.

Comment: Good point. That would be impossible. I updated my question just to deal with the German content being redirected. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess of `.com` and `.de` sites:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^de/(.*)$ http://mysite.de/content/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```